# Trouble capturing 'Enter key' press event on Android 13 in Ionic/Angular app. How to prevent focus change and call API?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic6, android-13

I have problem in ionic/angular mobile app.
I can catch press event "Enter key" until android 12 but I can catch press event "Enter key" in android 13. When one number input in screen, I can catch event press event "enter key" but when several number inputs when click "Enter key", I can catch event press event "Enter key" and the focus is change into next number input.
I would like to call API when click "Enter key", not changed focus.
Please help me.
Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ger9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHXZ9.png)

I would like get the codes or solutions to call API when click "Enter key"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To resolve, prevent default behavior of "Enter key" press event on input fields. Implement a custom event handler to call API without changing focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

In your HTML template, bind the (keydown.enter) event to a function that handles the "Enter key" press:

```
<!-- Assuming you have an input field -->
<input type="text" (keydown.enter)="onEnterPressed($event)">
```

In your component TypeScript file, define the onEnterPressed function to handle the "Enter key" press event. Within this function, prevent the default behavior of changing focus and instead call your API:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service'; // Assuming you have an ApiService for making API calls

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  onEnterPressed(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of changing focus

    // Call your API here
    this.apiService.callYourApi();

    // Optionally, you can keep the focus on the current input field
    // If you want to change focus, you can programmatically do so
    // Example: event.target.blur(); // to remove focus from the current input
  }
}
```

With this implementation, when the "Enter key" is pressed on any input field, it will trigger the onEnterPressed function, preventing the default focus change behavior, and instead calling your API. You can further customize this behavior as per your requirements.